Error : The bot is not part of the conversation roster. while sending message in channel through bot
We have a bot that can be installed in a Team as well as in personal scope.
We are facing issue when bot is trying to send  message in the channel where it is installed.
It was working fine few days back but all of a sudden it's throwing error that

{"error":{"code":"BotNotInConversationRoster","message":"The bot is
not part of the conversation roster."}}
Details :
teamId :19:3684c109f05f44efb4fb54a988d70286@thread.tacv2
Error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
StackTrace: at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.CreateConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(ConversationParameters
parameters, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken
cancellationToken) at
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.CreateConversationAsync(IConversations
operations, ConversationParameters parameters, CancellationToken
cancellationToken) at
Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.WelcomeBotCloundStorage.sendMessageInChannel(ConnectorClient
connectorClient, String cId, String tenantId, Activity activity)

Below is my code:
var channelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Channel = new ChannelInfo(cId),
                    Team = new TeamInfo(cId),
                    Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId)
                };
                var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
                {
                    IsGroup = true,
                    Bot = null,
                    ChannelData = channelData,
                    Members = null,
                    Activity = activity,
                };
                await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);

The bot is able to send direct message to users
